# Capture desktop screenshot as vector image and place into clipboard using MFC

Tags: mfc

I am developing an MFC application, where I need to capture the desktop and save as a vector image.

I can capture screen shot as `.BMP` and write to clipboard with following code.

```
int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap =CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC,
                        nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hCaptureDC,hCaptureBitmap);
BitBlt(hCaptureDC,0,0,nScreenWidth,nScreenHeight,
       hDesktopDC,0,0,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

// save bitmap to clipboard
OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hCaptureBitmap);
CloseClipboard();

// clean up
SelectObject(hCaptureDC, old_obj);
DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hDesktopDC);
DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
```

But I am looking something similar code which would allow me to **capture screenshot as vector image and place into clipboard**; so, I can read as EMF from clipboard.
I tried searching for MFC functions to convert raster images to vector images from clipboard, but I have not found anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A screenshot gathers pixel data only. All information on how those pixels were generated (which is essentially what an EMF would store) is lost. It's not possible to recover the GDI calls issued to construct the final image.

Even if that were possible, EMF wouldn't be capable of representing rendering information for image data that is not produced by the GDI (e.g. Qt applications with an OpenGL/Direct2D rasterizer, WPF applications, or UWP applications).